# Why is Terraria having frame-rate and game-play issues?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, terraria

A friend and I are trying to play Terraria, but we are having issues. Whenever we play it, our game tends to have terrible frame rate drops and the game slowing down incredibly, to the point of it being unplayable. It was like the computer was having a hard time running it, though it should not be having a hard time at all.

What should I or could I do to try and make the game run better, or to be playable at all?

My computer is a Inspiron 7559, with an i7-6700HQ core. The frame rate issue seems to effect me both when I am on a server and on single player. The only other apps up are Discord and Steam.

Comment: Could you give more information on the hardware? Do you have any other apps on your computer? Does your computer have a virus? What of your connection? You need to check these to make sure the computer can handle it, or if it has malware or if one of your internet connections are bad.

Comment: @TheMattBat999 I can post my computer specs, but it was an upgrade to my last PC (which was able to run Terraria fine).

Comment: The only thing I can think of is your GPU/CPU cycling isn't correct, there isn't enough power from the power supply, or you have some malware (a harmful virus, in which is rare).

Comment: Also, is it only Terraria lagging or is it the whole computer?

Comment: Also, if you have a notebook and 2 GPUs, integrated and dedicated, check if Terraria is running on the dedicated GPU, although I believe that with i7-6700HQ this shouldn't be the case - it should be powerful enough to deal with Terraria ;) Also try to play with video game settings by changing lightning, shadows and texture quality to low to see if it affects your Terraria experience.

Comment: @TheMattBat999 Only Terraria does this. I did some research and turned on Frame Skip, which fixed the problem, but I want to find a solution that lets me keep the game on the normal settings.

Answer (score -2):

Servers can get laggy some times. Anyway, If this happens, you can set the settings on a lower level, just hit the escape key and go to settings. Discord can make Terraria lag a lot sometimes, even If your RAM or Processor is good. Try to close Steam and Discord while your not using it. A other reason is that there might be a virus On the computer, they can really make your computer slower then expected. I hope it works sooner or later, good luck.